# HTML page does not render properly when using express.js

Tags: javascript, html

I am just testing to display a home page (index.html page) using express.js. This index page loads/renders perfectly on my browser when I load directly form the browser. However when I tried to load the same page via express.js I do not get the same effect. It just displays all the elements and pictures with its css styling line by line. Can anyone let me know whats missing? The index page I am loading is from a template. Below is the getwebapp.js file with the route. I am only showing the route to the index page only.

**getwebapp.js content:**

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const path = require('path');
const router = express.Router();

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname + 'public')));

router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/index.html'));});

router.get('/about", function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/about.html'));});

app.use('/', router);
app.listen(8080, () => console.log('Listening on port 8080....'));
console.log('Server started at ' + Date());
```

**index.html content (top half)**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Hello World</title>

    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <!-- Swiper CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/swiper.min.css">
    <!-- Styles -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="js/custom.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
   <header class="site-header">
     <div class="nav-bar">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
               <div class="col-12 d-flex flex-wrap justify-content-between align-items-center">
                  <div class="site-branding d-flex align-items-center">
                      <a class="d-block" href="index.html" rel="home"><img class="d-block" src="images/logo.png" alt="logo"></a>
                       </div><!-- .site-branding -->

                       <nav class="site-navigation d-flex justify-content-end align-items-center">
                         <ul class="d-flex flex-column flex-lg-row justify-content-lg-end align-items-center">
                                <li class="current-menu-item"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                                <li><a href="/about">About us</a></li>
                                <li><a href="/services">Services</a></li>
                                <li><a href="/news">News</a></li>
                                <li><a href="/contact">Contact</a></li>

                                <li class="call-btn button gradient-bg mt-3 mt-md-0">
                                    <a class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center" href="#"><img src="images/emergency-call.png"> +34 586 778 8892</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </nav><!-- .site-navigation -->
```

Comment: It looks like you're just serving static content; you're not running any middleware, you're not doing any template rendering, so: why declare `app.get` routes at all? Just use [app.static](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html) and done. Alternatively, if you _do_ want to render from template, don't use `res.sendFile`, use `res.render`.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly render html page with node js (express js). Use [express.static](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html) . i Have been read how to render html page using express js from this [website](https://codeforgeek.com/2015/01/render-html-file-expressjs/)

Hope this can help you

Comment: when to the website as suggested above and did exactly the same thing no change it only display all the elements with its css styling line by line not rendered as a proper HTML page.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the header to html

```
app.get("/", function(req, res) {
    res.type('html');
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "index.html"));
});
```

If that doesn't work, [try](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#router):

> ```
> app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
> app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/files'));
> app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/uploads'));
> ```

Comment: did what as suggested above for both cases output the same thing no change it only display all the elements with its css styling line by line and not rendered as a proper HTML page. –

Answer (score 0):

I have used the below method to solve this problem.

1. First I created APIs to render the HTML page in Express for different URLs viz.

[Picture of backend apis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S2uJ3.png)

2. Then from the frontend js file I was just changing the current page URL to render those HTML pages for which the APIs were already created.

[Picture of url changing for hitting api](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nPDri.png)